# Error generating final archive: Debug certificate expired on

Tags: java, android, certificate

I know how to fix the problem, but the thing is, my .android directory became invisible, and i don't know how to delete it. I tried with command lines like : rmdir /S .android, and it didn't work. I'm on a mac.

Comment: a `.directory` is always "invisible" thats the purpose of that `.` - you can still go (`cd .android`) there or `rm -rf ".android"` (no idea if that works on a mac - it should on linux)

Comment: that's what i just did, thanks

Comment: removing `debug.keystore` worked for me. It is probably in the C:/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's okay i found it :

On the OSX platform, if you manually remove the ~/.android directory using rm -rf ~/.android, then try to run the emulator, it crashes. This happens because the emulator fails to create a new .android directory before attempting to create the child SDK1.0 directory. To work around this issue, manually create a new .android directory using mkdir ~/.android, then run the emulator. The emulator creates the SDK1.0 directory and starts normally.

And i had to recreate some AVD, that's all.

Answer (score 14):

Remove `debug.keystore` from your user Android directory.

Comment: Well this will work , but where is debug.keystore ? 
Windows -> Preferences
Select Android -> Build
Check for "Default debug keystore: "